# Upwork app keeps asking for permission to take screenshot

Tags: permissions, screenshot

I am on Ubuntu 21.10
For my work I use Upwork desktop client to take screenshots.

Up until few days ago, it worked in the background without any issue.
Few days ago it started to ask permission each time it wants to take a screenshot.

How do I give it permission once for all?
It is very annoying to give permission every 10 minutes.

Please help.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. The reason for the behaviour is logging in using Wayland. The problem can be solved by logging in with Xorg.

You can see the steps here: https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

It worked on my Ubuntu 22.04.